# Should I use/avoid member variables in NGXS states?

Tags: angular, oop, ngxs

I'm using NGXS state management in my Angular 8 application and I was wondering if it is a good idea to let a State class have private (or public) member variables.

Taken from the NGXS-Documentation (https://www.ngxs.io/concepts/state), say there was a `ZooState`, but with an additional member `zoosLittleSecret`:

```js
@State<ZooStateModel>({
  name: 'zoo',
  defaults: {
    feed: false
  }
})
export class ZooState {

  private zoosLittleSecret: string;

  constructor(private zooService: ZooService) {}
}
```

What are the pros and cons of doing something like this?

Comment: What worries you? I'm not sure that your question is correct because it sounds like "if it's a good idea to let any class have private/public members. Do you keep private/public members in your component classes? I'm sure you do. `ZooState` is just a class and you can keep anything you want there.

Comment: The question is not about any class, it is especially about State classes.
To my mind, in OOP, member variables describe the state of an object derived from a class - but does that interfere with the architectural idea of NGXS for managing state where we have an own model type (`ZooStateModel`) for the state of the application?

Comment: There is nothing in NGXS documentation that tells "do not use public/private members in state classes". `zooService` that is an instance of `ZooService` is also a private member, why would you use it there then? NGXS's architectural idea is CQRS, but it's not related to public and private members in classes :D I'd say you have to care about more important things that about this one.